# XMPP Strophe.JS Application Security Concern

Tags: javascript, security, xmpp, chat, strophe

I'm looking for a good XMPP Chat Application standard for web platform (like eBuddy, Facebook Chat, etc.) I've googled some XMPP libraries for web application and my choice goes to Strophe.js since it is very simple and robust.

But I'm not sure to developing a pure Javascript application because of security concern. Most of modern browser could see your Javascript code by inspect element feature like Google Chrome does. I'm afraid this could be a critical problem in future days. All people could see and know your application logic and what your application does behind the scene.

My question is it possible to combining Strophe.js and server-side programming (eg. PHP, ASP.NET, etc). I mean using Strophe.js as a View-Tier and server-side programming as Controller-Tier?

Or is it possible to hide your Javascript code, so that user could not see the details behind the scene of you application?

What is the best practice?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your security concerns are.

My concern was the username and password public. Our web app is MVC and I built a class that creates/logs in the users and passes the SID, RID and JID back out to the front end (Strophe) to then attach to the jabber server to start chatting. See http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html for more. Essentially create the xml strings, send to the jabber server and manage the responses as shown in xep 206.

Comment: did you combine any server-side programming on your app?
or is it a pure javascript?

Comment: Yes, wrote a couple classes in C# to get the username and pw from the datbase, send to the jabber server using the xep 206 process. You have to initiate, then authenicate, then restart, bind and set the session. I found that I needed to announce the presence a well. This process will give you the SID and JID. You create the RID by creating a random int and incrementing it each time. Pass those 3 items out to strophe then attach. Take a look at http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/. It's in django, but gives you a good visual of the process.

Comment: did you using any XMPP-C# libraries for user authentication or you doing it manually? you're developing asp.net with C#, right?

Comment: Our app is MVC/c#. I rolled my own. Build and send the body in xep 206 as a webrequest (in c#), convert the returned stream into a XML document and analyze the response. The response will tell you what to do next. Follow steps 3,4 & 5 on http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html#initiate and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I come back with another issue, I'm using Strophe .attach(). But every time I refresh the page, the session is terminated 404 (Invalid SID). I'd already increment RID by 1. Should I regenerate SID & RID when reloading page?

Comment: You shouldn't have to regenerate the SID. How are you storing the SID & RID (and incrementing)?

Comment: I've incremented RID & store it on PHP session. But I realized that Strophe is automatically increment the RID on every request. So, when I open another tab my RID is already used.

Comment: No, because the connection is rejected if I send an already used RID. I've read about similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616429/session-resume-problem-with-strophe-attach-and-ejabberd
Now, my working solution is regenerate SID every time I reload a page or open a new tab.

Comment: I stashed my RID in a cookie and incremented it every time Strophe incremented it, I updated the cookie. When arriving on a new page, I grab from the cookie.

Comment: How to know when does Strophe increment its RID? Is it on any request occurred right? Is there any event Strophe onRequest so I can store it on cookie?

Comment: The _processRequest method in Strophe processes your requests. Follow that to find where the rid gets incremented. You can create something like the rawOutput logging (or use that) also/too.